# Convert multiple unicode values to corresponding text in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, unicode

If my Unicode character contains more than one hex value in an Excel cell, how do I write a function in Excel to convert it into the corresponding character?

For example:
Unicode Hex values in Excel cell: `0B15 0B4D 0B37`. 
Character to be formed out of above values: `କ୍ଷ` (Odia/Indian language)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert unicode to corresponding text in Excel spreadsheet](http://superuser.com/questions/308865/convert-unicode-to-corresponding-text-in-excel-spreadsheet)

Comment: I believe that this question is not a duplicate, because the older question addresses only the conversion of a single UTF-16 / UCS-2 code point into a character, whereas this question deals with the *compositing* of a sequence of combining code points *into a single glyph*.

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

Install the following **U**ser **D**efined **F**unction *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function qwerty(r As Range) As Variant
   Dim L As Long, CH As String, CH2 As String
   arr = Split(ActiveCell.Text, " ")
   For Each a In arr
      L = Application.WorksheetFunction.Hex2Dec(a)
      CH = ChrW(L)
      CH2 = CH2 & CH
   Next a
   qwerty = CH2
End Function
```

Then pick some cell, say cell **B1**, format it to *Arial Unicode MS* and enter:

```
=qwerty(A1)
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=qwerty(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: I have tried the code, but it is not giving the result as shown.

Comment: @AjitKumarNayak  Have you used the suggested *font*??  With the wrong font you will see question marks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work because I needed the same thing.

```
Public Function qwerty(r As Range) As Variant
   Dim arr() As String
   Dim CH As String, CH2 As String
   Dim a As Variant
   a = 0
   arr = Split(r.Text, " ", -1, vbTextCompare)
   For Each a In arr
      CH = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unichar(a)
      CH2 = CH2 & CH
   Next a
   qwerty = CH2
End Function
```